# Browser skips animation of div

Tags: javascript, function, animation

experienced programmers,

i wrote a simple function to animate a div:

```
<script>
function okenko(y1, y2, dy) 
{
vyska = document.getElementById("okenko");
y1=y1+dy;

if (y1<=y2) {
  vyska.style.bottom = y1+'px';
  alert(y1);
  setTimeout(okenko(y1, y2, dy),30);
  }
else {
  vyska.style.bottom = y2+'px'
  }
}
</script>
```

plus triggering button and div:

```
<input type="button" onclick="okenko(-60,0,5);" value="Okénko">
<div id="okenko" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;">
```

It works fine with the alert() inserted - but if you remove it, the animation is skipped. What is the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Btw. it is a good practice to name functions in English, not in Czech :)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: Why not use whatever you're comfortable with?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
setTimeout(okenko(y1, y2, dy),30);
```

...**calls** `okenko(y1, y2, dy)` immediately, and passes its *return value* (`undefined`) into `setTimeout` (which ends up doing nothing), exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

You probably meant:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    okenko(y1, y2, dy);
}, 30);
```

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: Er, um, I have no idea what you mean. There's clearly a `;` there. ;-)